# Error in executing ./network.sh up createChannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I was implementing the fabric v2.2 Hyperledger fabric sample > test-network, all the binaries and module versions are updated and satisfied but while creating channel getting this error as highlighted as shown [click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW7Wy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used v2.2 before but I have successfully used v1.4 and 2.1 before and what can tell you is that "join transactions" are submitted to the orderer in the network.

The orderer has a port number of 7050. So you can try the code below to see if your orderer is listening on port 7053 or 7050.

```
telnet localhost 7053
telnet localhost 7050
```

Before trying the codes, make sure you start your network.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer, It is connected at localhost 7053 and while setting my network up which is doing fine I guess that means orderers are ported successfully right? but while creating channels its not working. :(

Comment: Running the network successfully means that the orderer is running but does not guarantee that it is running on the specified port. If you can confirm that the scripts you're running are from the official Github repository, I could check it and see what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: Line 27 of [docker file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml) says that the orderer should be running on port 7050. This is confirmed by line 45 of the [channel configuration file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml).

Comment: The [onsadmin](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/osnadminchannel.html) command specifies that -o is the orderer's address which should be running on 7050.

Comment: I would recommend modifying line 40  of [this file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/scripts/createChannel.sh) and try again.

Comment: Yes, I am using same fabric-sample repo and I applied the changes you suggested in line 40, it matches with the repo itself but yet again it is giving same error..

Comment: I just downloaded Fabric v2.2.1 and run it successfully. Can you run 
"git checkout" in your folder so that I check out your version.

Comment: Hi, I was working with v2.2.4 but now when I deleted all the docker images and downloaded new images i.e v2.2.1 it works .. thanks for helping